# here-document that disables shell parsing

Tags: bash, heredoc

I need a here document for uploading `TeX` to an online shell. I don't want the shell to do anything with the contents. The following MWE is the best I have managed so far.

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/mytex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test mathematics:  $ 2^{10} = 1024$ works but
$e^{i\pi} = -1$ is mangled because no space follows the $e$.
"double" and 'single' quotes should be preserved too.
\end{document}
EOF
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/mytex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test mathematics:  $ 2^{10} = 1024$ works but
$e^{i\pi} = -1$ is mangled because no space follows the $e$.
"double" and 'single' quotes should be preserved too.
\end{document}
EOF
```

[From the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[-]word
         here-document 
delimiter
```

> If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the
>   result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document
>   are not expanded.

Comment: It's a lesson in reading the manual! For my use case, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101479/how-to-build-two-different-tex-files-from-same-tex-file/101484#101484